# Calling AsyncTask from listview adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I want to run an asynctask of an activity from the getview method of listview adapter. The code is:

```
AsyncRecordShow ars =( (BaseScreen) _context).new AsyncShowView("",serId, evntId);
ars.execute();
```

Its throwing an ClassCastException :

```
07-02 16:51:04.697: E/AndroidRuntime(12841): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.myapp.skyapp.BaseScreen
```

How can i do this? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: post proper code so we can find out something.

Comment: The error says it all, why are you casting the context?

Comment: AsyncRecordShow ars =new AsyncShowView("",    serId, evntId);
ars.execute();

Comment: Its in the getView method of listview adapter, that why i am given the context of baseclass

Answer (score 0):

try `AsyncRecordShow ars =(_context).new AsyncShowView("",serId, evntId);`